# Migrate EF Migrations to EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I have about 40 migrations in my current .NET Framework application. I am porting the Database and all it's repositories to a .NET Standard library because an new application is written in .NET Core, which results in double implementations of repositories and in the .NET Core app we had to use Dapper to not conflict with anything else.

So, I could easily port the `IdentityDbContext` and all the other related things  to `EntityFrameworkCore`.

But now the Migrations. I know Microsoft has a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on retrieving the models and DbContext from the database. However this creates a very long `OnModelCreating` method with all the configurations. Looks like this could work But, if I want to do any new changes I have to change it there and within a new migration and make sure there are no conflicts. 
Also, our current migrations have manual adjustments that makes sure it will work for a new database or an existing production database. Something not taken care of this way.

What I want is to migrate the existing, individual, migration files to the new code syntax. I don't care if the manual adjustments are left out, but if somehow the biggest things are converted automatically.

For example:

.NET Framework:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.AdditionalCosts",
        c => new
            {
                additionalCostId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                shoppingCartId = c.Int(),
                shoppingCartProductId = c.Int(),
                orderId = c.Int(),
                inclPrice = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 3),
                taxPrice = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 3),
                description = c.String(),
                title = c.String(),
                costType = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.additionalCostId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Orders", t => t.orderId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.ShoppingCartProducts", t => t.shoppingCartProductId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.ShoppingCarts", t => t.shoppingCartId)
        .Index(t => t.shoppingCartId)
        .Index(t => t.shoppingCartProductId)
        .Index(t => t.orderId);
}
```

.NET Core:

Is there somewhere a converting tool available?

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        "dbo.AdditionalCosts",
        c => new
        {
            additionalCostId = c.Column<int>(nullable: false), //idnetity: true?
            shoppingCartId = c.Column<int>(),
            shoppingCartProductId = c.Column<int>(),
            orderId = c.Column<int>(),
            inclPrice = c.Column<decimal>(nullable: false), //precision: 18, scale: 3?
            taxPrice = c.Column<decimal>(nullable: false), //precision: 18, scale: 3
            description = c.Column<string>(),
            title = c.Column<string>(),
            costType = c.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        }, constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_AdditionalCost", t => t.additionalCostId);//default naming of PK_? why not automated anymore! :(
            //etc..
        });
        //.PrimaryKey(t => t.additionalCostId)
        //.ForeignKey("dbo.Orders", t => t.orderId)
        //.ForeignKey("dbo.ShoppingCartProducts", t => t.shoppingCartProductId)
        //.ForeignKey("dbo.ShoppingCarts", t => t.shoppingCartId)
        //.Index(t => t.shoppingCartId)
        //.Index(t => t.shoppingCartProductId)
        //.Index(t => t.orderId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually had a few options:

1. Go over every table, get the correct index names, column names and create the migration files yourself.
2. Go back in time with the code and generate every migration again with EFCore.
3. Generate one migration with the current code and somehow try to align the current database.

   - Problem: EFCore generates indexes and some FK names differently.

So.. eventually I just generated a new migration with the current code, did a Schema comparison within Visual Studio to check the real differences and make adjustments to your migration if needed. Then, migrate the current data to the new database when releasing. I am currently in the process of doing this so I might adjust this answer later.